# Trim long navigation if it goes off screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a bit help with this thing I am trying to write. I don't need code, just a bit of help with the logic.

So I have this navigation, that at any point can be a different width with different number of anchors in it. If it happens to be longer than the wrapping container, I must trim it, put "..." and if the user clicks on the dots, the remaining items must show in a dropdown.

Ok for now, but the navigation is also sticky. And when it sticks to top, I must reduce a logo and share (sometimes also language selector) from its width. When it goes back to being static, I must again update it, and show elements that I previously trimmed.

All of those "extra" elements, that I must reduce from the width, are containers somewhere in the website, that do not have special classes or anything special in them, pure content (it comes from a CMS, and that cannot be changed).

I would appreciate any type of help!

Thanks!

Comment: although you do not need code in answers, you can put an example for understand better your problem

Comment: Which part do you need help with?

Comment: Without a better explanation of your problem, some things you can try:  You can target elements with different selectors in CSS, they don't necessarily have to have classes.  Also there are ways to truncate text in CSS and JavaScript. Hard to tell you which to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the dimensions of the navigation, I would say the following steps might help:

1. Always have an ellipsis element, with a hidden class, toggled as needed.
2. Using jquery $('navElement').offset().left + $('navElement').width you get the right end position for the nav.
3. Now you can get the element at this position, maybe using Document.elementFromPoint(),
4. Identify all elements after this element, you'll have to figure out the logic for this, make them display block, and wrap all of them within a container dynamically.
5. now showing hiding that container will result in a dropdown effect.
6. As long as you can identify the logo and other components you want toshow/hide when sticky using css selectors, when your nav goes sticky, add a parent class to your nav and write css to hide these elements when inside the sticky class.

That is the logic I would follow at a broad level based on your question.